# Keeping the validation BindingResult from action phase to the view in spring portlet in Liferay 6.2

Tags: spring, liferay-6

I created a spring portlet with controller class and validator class.

Normally in spring,  error messages added in validator class are used jsp page.

Validator class code snippet:

```
ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(arg1, "heightInFeet",
"required.heightInFeet","HeightInFeet is required");
```

In JSP page, below is code:

```
<form:errors path="heightInFeet" cssClass="errors"/>
```

I am very confused in liferay spring portlet, how to add this error msg?

Comment: Please put code formatting around code.

Comment: hi i want to display my error msg like next to field in form in liferay?is there any way to retrieve error msg from validator class?